# Trying to export an FBX

Tags: export

I'm trying to export some models as an .fbx, but when I finish exporting the meshes somehow rotate, scale and change locations.

Here are some screenshots.

[image: The meshes in question]

[image: Exporting the FBX]

[image: They somehow change]

If someone can help me I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have keyframes for scale rotation and location.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: Remove the keyframes?

Comment: Yeah thanks, I didn't know what a keyframe was at the moment but I already managed to delete them :)